# Passing Json response to view in Rails Ajax Datatable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an index method that respond with Json call to `Datatable` such as:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: PeopleDatatable.new(params, user: current_user, view_context: view_context) }
end
```

I would like to be able to pass an array of all the IDs in the response to a dom in my view such as `<div id: "people">1,2,3,4</div>`

As per the gem description, the People records are generated in the

```
app/datatables/people_datatable.rb
```

using:

```
def get_raw_records
  User.all
end
```

I tried adding the following in the view's script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<%= peoples_path(format: :json) %>",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data.name)
            $('#bouba').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

but the result is an undefined object class.

What would be the easiest way to do so please?

I am using the following gem for my datatable [Rails ajax Datatable](https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails/issues)

Comment: how are you telling PeopleDatatable the list of ids that you wish to render?

Comment: @LesNightingill, just added the origine of the data, therefore the ids.

Comment: you don't need the Datatable gem just to show a list of ids. Just use `render json: {user_ids: User.pluck(:id)}`

Comment: The reason why I am using the datatable gem is because I am also refreshing a datatable via Ajax on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `/people.json` and see what you get as a response, it looks something like this:

```json
{
  "recordsTotal": 2,
  "recordsFiltered": 2,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": ""
    },
  ]
}
```

Now that you know what the structure looks like, send ajax request to that url:

```html
<div id="people-ids"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      // send request to the correct url: "/people.json"
      url: "<%= people_path(format: :json) %>",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function({data}) {
        //              ^
        // extract "data" attribute from the response

        console.log(data) // you can see what you get in the console
        
        // extract ids
        const user_ids = data.map(user => user.id)

        // do what you like with the ids
        $("#people-ids").html(user_ids.join());
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: it works, i wasnt that far actually, THANK YOU. I have one last question. I would like to pass these IDs to a button  in a link_to: <%= link_to select_all_checkbox_peoples_path, method: :put, remote: true do %>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-square-check" style="font-size: 20px; color: #e8e8e8"></i>
<% end %>

as arguments. Would you know how to pass the data from JS to link_to dynamically please ?

Comment: @ReneChan you can't pass data from *JS* to *Ruby*. Javascript runs on the front end - the browser. Ruby runs on the backend - the server. You can update the generated `a` html tag that `link_to` helper creates. Something like this: `$("#some-link").href= \`/people?user_ids=${user_ids}\``

Comment: Hi Alex, may i ask for you help in the continuation of my work please? I created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73848604/updating-a-div-via-ajax-within-a-datatable-ajax-call. Would you also have the answer by any chance please ?