# Updating a div via Ajax within a Datatable Ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I would like to make a single Ajax call to update not only a datatable but a div that is located elsewhere in the page. I am using Ajax-datatable-rails gem. I buit the upper part of the ajax call such as:

```
$('#people-datatable').dataTable
    processing: true
    order: []
    serverSide: true
    ajax: data: (d) ->
      d.url = $('#people-datatable').data('source');
      success: ({ data }) ->
        people_ids = data.map (people) -> people.DT_RowId
        $("#bouba").html people_ids.join()
      return
```

Alternatively, i also tried the following with no success (data does not exist for the second Ajax call):

```
  $('#people-datatable').dataTable
    processing: true
    order: []
    serverSide: true
    ajax: data: (d) ->
      d.url = $('#people-datatable').data('source');
      d.recordsTotal = $.ajax({
        url: $('#people-datatable').data('source'),
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        success: ({ data }) ->
          people_ids = data.map (people) -> people.DT_RowId
          $("#bouba").html people_ids.join()
          return
      });
      return
```

(I have remove the rest of the code that i related to the columns)

It does not look like the success triggers, as nothing happens after the data are loaded.
What would be the right way please ?

(I am looking to retrieve ALL the IDs in my query, beyond the one from the current page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#people-datatable').dataTable
  processing: true
  order: []
  serverSide: true
  ajax: data: (d) ->
    d.url = $('#people-datatable').data('source');
    d.recordsTotal = $.ajax({
      url: $('#people-datatable').data('source'),
      dataType: "json",
      type: 'GET',
       async: false,
      success: ({ data }) ->
        people_ids = data.map (people) -> people.DT_RowId
        $("#bouba").html people_ids.join()
        return
    }).responseJSON.recordsTotal;
    return
```

Or try you can using the drawCallback option of the datatable. This option is called after each draw of the datatable. You can use it to update the #bouba dom. Here is an example:

```
$('#people-datatable').dataTable
  processing: true
  order: []
  serverSide: true
  drawCallback: ->
    people_ids = @api().rows().data().map (people) -> people.DT_RowId
    $("#bouba").html people_ids.join()
  ajax: data: (d) ->
    d.url = $('#people-datatable').data('source');
    return
```

Comment: thank you, it looks good. But i have a question please. When i filter the table, I would like the #bouba dom to automatically update at a the same time.  Right now when the page loads, it does put the people ids in the #bouba dom, but when filtering nothing happens (i used the first method, not the callback).

Comment: I edited the answer. Try the second option.

Comment: There is no way i could have found this !!! thank you very much, it works perfectly! (Need to wait for 5hrs for Bounty)

Comment: i have a question/problem please. The solution that you have only returns the IDs on the current page. Is there a way to return all the IDs of the query please ?

Comment: any chance you can help me with this versioning please ?

Comment: I'll take a look today.

Comment: Try: d.length = -1

Comment: The length parameter is the number of records that the table can display in the current draw. It is expected that the number of records returned will be equal to this number, unless the server has fewer records to return. Note that this can be -1 to indicate that all records should be returned (although that negates any benefits of server-side processing!)

Comment: must be placed on the line before return.